# MySQL execute 2 queries to the same table simultaneously

Tags: mysql, sql, database

New values are added to a MySQL Database all day long.  There are over 8 million rows in this table.  Because there are a lot of old values, I want to clean these up without stopping the Java Program Inserting the values.

I am sending this query to the MySQL:

```
DELETE FROM `tablename`
WHERE `from` <= (date_add(now(), interval -20 DAY))
```

but what happens is that the Java Program stops adding new values to the table.  It there any way I can handle this without editing the Java Program?
I would be willing to run the query as a cronjob once a day.

I have also tried working with the parameter LOW_PRIORITY, but it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: is your table MyISAM or InnoDb not that proeficient. But you should be able to change the locking level from Table level to row level. 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-lock-modes.html

Comment: You say the java program stops adding records.  What are the details?  Does it throw an error?

Comment: Could you please clarify how the `oracle` tag is relevant to your question?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are using old MyISAM db engine.

Unfortunately MyISAM uses table-level locking. When a row is inserted, updated or deleted, all other changes to that table are held up until that request has been completed. In your case long running `DELETE` blocks any `INSERT`s into that table.

You can improve it by changing your table engine to InnoDB like this:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ENGINE = innodb;
```

InnoDB engine is fully transactional and does not lock whole table during `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`, so your problem should go away.

Comment: more info on table locking there: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-locking.html
Btw MyISAM is not the 'old' db engine it's just an engine for different purposes, it is still maintained etc.

Comment: @charly: it depends on who you talk to. IMO, lack of transactions support by MyISAM and crappy locking makes it old and obsolete

Comment: I am not an expert at all so I won't get really crazy about that. But from what I have read MyISAM ends up being really good on read intensive tables. Wouldn't be that pretty good for data mining for example? or just for tables which are really often read but rarely updated?

Comment: In my experience in data mining, RDBMSs are rarely used.

Comment: @mvp "That is, you can insert rows into a MyISAM table at the same time other clients are reading from it." (from the doc) so that means for applications that don't need a really strong transactional support and don't use updates much. So let's say the Fb wall for eg would be better on a MyISAM table than an InnoDb engine. Nope?

Comment: @charly: in MyISAM, `INSERT` does not lock `SELECT`, but it does lock `UPDATE` or `DELETE`. In other words, if your table has more than 1 client, you will run into concurrency issues once in a while. And when number of clients and table size increases, this gets exponentially worse - it does not scale.

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine you need to change your storage engine. Do this using `ALTER TABLE tbl ENGINE = innodb`, but do be aware of the [differences between MyISAM and Innodb](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/01/12/should-you-move-from-myisam-to-innodb/).